# Select results from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a social website.I have an alert option which needs to show the friend requests and unread messages together based on the time it arrives in various div's .Actually I am lack of logic about how to display results from two tables.Kindly help me.

My tables are:

```
1)sk_friends=>[friendship_id, from_user_id, to_user_id, status,date]
```

status contains `accepted` or `pending` as values.

```
2)sk_messages=>[msg_id, from_user_id, to_user_id,text, date, status]
```

Comment: and what about the message status (read or unread)? It is not there.

Comment: what result do you want to get>

Comment: @JW I want to display the results in a div.If the current row is a friend request,I need to display his/her name,picture,two buttons for accept or reject.If it is a message,I need to display the message,sender name and his photo

Comment: @Uttara If the message is read,there is status column,I have forgotten to write in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM sk_friends JOIN sk_message ON sk_friends.from_user_id = sk_message.from_user_id
```

this will be the basic query for retrieving records from two tables..

try this.. but not sure how much will help you

Comment: I need to display friend request if it is in the current row,or messages

Comment: if you want to retrive only requests then message table is not necessary, isn't it??

Comment: I need to show the messages also if it is in the current row. ie,if a message comes,then a friend request comes,again message comes,I need to show friend request,then message,again friend request in the alerts page

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to pull both pending friend requests and messages at the same time, you'll probably want to consider adding a more generic "notifications" style table, or run them as separate queries.

So you could go for a table along the lines of:

```
sk_notifications => [id, date, type, from_user, to_user, status]
```

Which would contain both types of events (new messages and new friend requests) - your code would then be responsible for providing the different actions based on the notification type.

Answer (score 0):

for friend request see the query below

```
select * from sk_friends where (logged_in_user_id in from_user_id or logged_in_user_id in to_user_id) and status='pending';
```

and for message unread

```
 select * from sk_messages where to_user_id=logged_in_user_id;
```